# Android Navigation Drawer change content

Tags: android

When I click navigation drawer items, how to make the page content change without creating or going to a new activity?

I don't want to use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyNextActivity.class);
startactivity(intent);
```

I want the page to stay here, not open a new page.

Any suggestions about how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you are looking for navigation drawer with fragments. Check this link on how to create one with fragments.
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer
Or just search for navigation drawer with fragments.

Comment: You need to use fragments for that. You can check a simple example like this http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2014/05/simple-navigation-drawer-example-in.html

Answer (score 2):

You might want to go through the official documentation here: [Creating a Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

You can change switch fragments on click of an item in the navigation drawer as explained here: [Building a Dynamic UI with Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

The `content_frame` in the first tutorial can be treated as the `fragment_container` in [this section](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) of the second tutorial.